# String variable substitution in selection expression

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, expression, where-clause

I'm trying to put a variable into a string used to do a selection. At the moment it's like this:

```
expression = "'No_Props' > 5 AND %s < 200 AND 'ST_Ori' >60" % metres_field
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(streets_table, "NEW_SELECTION", '"' + expression + '"')
```

Printing the expression gives this:

```
'No_Props' > 5 AND 'Shape_Le_2' < 200 AND 'ST_Ori' >60
```

which I thought would work.

I've tried several things. Originally the expression was in a docstring:

```
"""'No_Props' > 5 AND %s < 200 AND 'ST_Ori' >60""" % metres_field
```

but that didn't work

I considered using the **doc** attribute but it only worked on a function (not a variable)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and how to make it work?

The expression looks like it should do the trick when it's printed out.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000071000000), the query string does not need to include surrounding quotations.  Note that although you printed `expression`--which was a good thing to do--you did *not* print the value you are actually passing to `SelectLayerByAttribute_management`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted using the format() method, as below.

```
metres_field = "field_name"
expression = "{0} > 5 AND {1} < 200 AND {2} >60".format(""" "No_props" """, metres_field, """ "ST_Ori" """)
```

Also works with the docstring outside of the format method.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an ArcPy problem but a basic problem in Python (and I don't know ArcPy):

1. From Python 2.6, % is deprecated, use .format() (except in some cases)
2. So if you want to get a result like arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "SUBSET_SELECTION", **' "population" > 10000 '**) as in [Select Layer By Attribute (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000071000000)

One solution is:

```
expression  = "{0} > 5 AND {1} < 200 AND {2} >60".format(""" "No_props" """,""" "Shape_Le_2" """,""" "ST_Ori" """)
```

and the result is

```
' "No_props"  > 5 AND  "Shape_Le_2"  < 200 AND  "ST_Ori"  >60'
```

then

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(streets_table, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
```

but if you know Python, there are many others...

Comment: Thanks gene, informative answer. But.. I've still got the same issue here that I need to put a variable in the expression. 'Shape_Le_2' could have a different name, thus I need the variable 'metres_field' to be in the expression. I tried (""" metres_field """) but that didn't work

Comment: Thanks to you, I've cracked it.

`expression  = "{0} > 5 AND {1} < 200 AND {2} >60".format(""" "No_props" """, metres_field, """ "ST_Ori" """)`

Variable isn't enclosed in quotes or triple quotes in the format() method.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the error being thrown, I would first suggest that you need to enclose your fieldnames with quotation marks (") instead of the apostrophe (') you currently have. See the help bits for building your `where_clause` on the tool help [page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000071000000).

Comment: It depends what your source is. It gets confusing as sometimes you need exclamation point, single quotes, double quotes, or square brackets. This goes in depth about building SQL statements http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000

Comment: It can get confusing, however I believe (and I could definitely be wrong) that when specifying field names using Python, they will always be surrounded by either quotation marks (`"field_name"`) or by brackets (`[field_name]`), but not apostrophes (`'field_name'`). Apostrophes are used to surround strings in the SQL query: `"field_name" = 'some string'` or `[field_name] = 'some string'`

Comment: You are correct! Exlcamation points are used in field calculator for the Python parser and single quotes are used for strings.

Comment: OK thanks for that, I originally thought single and double quotations were interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe there should be a space between the > and the 60.

Also, usually in Python I see field names enclosed in !'s, not single quotes. For an example, [see this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000). May also need double quotes, based on that example, but I think the main issue is the !'s.

Comment: Odd thing is it works fine when I hard-code the string instead of using the %s value. I've used !'s for the calculate field but not for selection query expressions (and they've worked without probs) but if it's better practice I'll give that a try

Comment: Well, you're correct, !'s aren't required in code. You'd think I'd know that since looking at a script I wrote I used double quotes. But single quotes are still probably incorrect. Sorry for the error. My practice is to set field names to variables so I don't usually run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
expression = "\"No_Props\" > 5 AND \"%s\" < 200 AND \"ST_Ori\" > 60" % metres_field
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(streets_table, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't =\